# Create thumbnails will not work with 40+ images

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

Total php newbie here....I have been trying my best to learn and have compiled a script from the various tutorials online that scans a folder on the server. generates the thumbnails for the images found and then places the thumbnail into a newly created thumbs folder as needed...Then display the thumbnails in an html page with the thumbnails linked back to the bigger picture.

Everything is working great in my tests except once I implement it with 40+ images I get no response at all from the script. Just a blank html page with no body...

As I said I am new but i think it has something to do with the timeout of the server? Not able to render the amount of images  or something? I seen some things about server php.ini timeouts but am not sure this is the problem.

I just need to figure out why I can not do more then 40 images at a time and I will be golden!

```
<?php
# SETTINGS
$max_width = 300;
$max_height = 300;

function getPictureType($ext) {
    if ( preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i', $ext) ) {
        return 'jpg';
    } else if ( preg_match('/png/i', $ext) ) {
        return 'png';
    } else if ( preg_match('/gif/i', $ext) ) {
        return 'gif';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

function getPictures() {
    global $max_width, $max_height;
    if ( $handle = opendir(".") ) {
        $lightbox = rand();

        while ( ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
            if ( !is_dir($file) ) {
                $split = explode('.', $file); 
                $ext = $split[count($split) - 1];
                if ( ($type = getPictureType($ext)) == '' ) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ( ! is_dir('thumbs') ) {
                    mkdir('thumbs');
                }
                if ( ! file_exists('thumbs/'.$file) ) {
                    if ( $type == 'jpg' ) {
                        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                    } else if ( $type == 'png' ) {
                        $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                    } else if ( $type == 'gif' ) {
                        $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
                    }
                    if ( ($oldW = imagesx($src)) < ($oldH = imagesy($src)) ) {
                        $newW = $oldW * ($max_width / $oldH);
                        $newH = $max_height;
                    } else {
                        $newW = $max_width;
                        $newH = $oldH * ($max_height / $oldW);
                    }
                    $new = imagecreatetruecolor($newW, $newH);
                    imagecopyresampled($new, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newW, $newH, $oldW, $oldH);
                    if ( $type == 'jpg' ) {
                        imagejpeg($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
                    } else if ( $type == 'png' ) {
                        imagepng($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
                    } else if ( $type == 'gif' ) {
                        imagegif($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
                    }
                    imagedestroy($new);
                    imagedestroy($src);
                }
                echo "<div class=\"box\">";
                echo '<a href="'.$file.'" class="swipebox">';
                echo '<img src="thumbs/'.$file.'" alt="" />';
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<---HTML CODE BELOW HERE-->
Using this to call function above in html code:

<?php getPictures(); ?>
```

Comment: PHP by default has a timeout of 30 seconds that a script is allowed to run.  Your probably going over whatever the max is on your server

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a default timeout of 30 seconds. You will probably need to change this:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

This will stop the script from timing out if it takes a long time to execute.

Also, many web hosting services have limits on the CPU  and RAM that your page is allowed to use that you might be exceeding.  To get around this, you could break up your script into chunks and run the PHP file several times, processing like 30 of the images at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the help but still same issue...I added this and still nothing...but it works on smaller sampling of images...so frustrating!

         <?php
 set_time_limit(0);
 
 # SETTINGS

Comment: I've also had memory problems when dealing with lots of large images, but I'm not sure what to do about them... I'll look around.

Comment: I just ran your code using the `set_time_limit(0);` on my local server with 80 images (2000px by 1500px, around 1MB each) and didn't have any problems.  Are you running it on a local server or on the real web?  The operation used around 80MB RAM and 100% CPU for about 2 minutes on my computer.  You're host service (or local computer) might have limits that are being exceeded by this script.

Comment: You could break it up and run the PHP file several times, processing 30 of the images at a time.

Comment: just spoke with hosting company and they say I am at maximum of 74m for my limit....when I stated 40+ i do not know the number that it stopped as I did 30---then 150+....how do I brak out the function as you mentioned because I am now at least getting errors...Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 77594624 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20736 bytes)...i assume that would make things better and not take 2 minutes...lol at least that will only be the first time I run it, from then on the thumbnails will be there

Comment: Try running `gc_collect_cycles();` after the `imagedestroy($src);`.  This will cause PHP to remove all unneeded memory.  It cut the memory used by a lot.

Comment: ok will look into that...question about the 74m....does that mean the folder size I am trying to run this in cannot exceed 74m...so all my image files together need to be less then this?

Comment: No.  It just means that you can't go over 74MB _RAM_ in your PHP script.

Comment: great appreciate all the help...will do some more research on the split option and also look into the raw file size as i ahve some that are nearly 4mb and they really dont need to be that big for my purposes